# All emails stopped in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, php

No emails are being received in our M 2.3.4

For instance, customer welcome, password reset, contact us, etc.

Already checked all the settings under admin panel and there's no change in the settings at all.

Checked under Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings and it is enabled.

When checked under exception log file saw below, I think removing Mandrill extension would be an option to make it work. But wanted to understand from a professional.

`[2021-08-17 04:13:56] main.CRITICAL: 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:{"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:  at /var/www/html/app/code/Ebizmarts/MandrillSmtp/Model/Transport/Smtp.php:66, Zend\\Mail\\Protocol\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:  at /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php:348)"} []`

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Under Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings  there is a setting called "Disable Email Communications" if the value of this setting is "YES" then change it to "NO"

Comment: Hi Deep, yes it is already set to NO as I have mentioned in my post above. is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Are you using any extension for smtp configuration?

Comment: No, we use windows based server for email. Magepal SMTP extension is there but it was disabled long back.

Comment: @DeepJoshi I also updated the post above, when I saw the log, particularly the exception file I found this,
`2021-08-17 04:13:56] main.CRITICAL: 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: 
{"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:  at /var/www/html/app/code/Ebizmarts/MandrillSmtp/Model/Transport/Smtp.php:66, Zend\\Mail\\Protocol\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:  at /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php:348)"} []`

Comment: It seems that Mandrill Smtp is being used there for transaction email sending. Please check system configuration for this "Ebizmarts_MandrillSmtp" extension.  If it's enabled then verfiy the mandrill details are proper and mandrill smtp configured properly or not. And as you menitoned you are using windows based server and don't want to use this then would suggest to disable this extension. Let me know if it works.Thanks!

Comment: @DeepJoshi Thanks, yes actually we stopped using Mandrill/Mailchimp around month back. So only by disabling this extension should work? Or anything else is required?

Comment: Yes, If Mandrill_Mailchimp isn't in use please disable that. And make sure email configuration is proper at server level after that email sending should work. Thanks!

Comment: @DeepJoshi Thanks, I have disabled Mailchimp/Mandrill SMTP but still not getting any emails.  I have also enabled Magepal SMTP extension called SMTP Configuration and Settings (Gmail/Google/AWS/Office360 etc) from under Stores > Configuration > System but it didn't help either. What should I be checking for after enabling Magepal SMTP extension?